# Execute SSIS in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a SSIS package which will upload files into tables. I want to execute it as soon as a file has been uploaded and saved to a table. This [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27156/How-to-Call-SSIS-Package-from-the-Stored-Procedure) showed how to execute it using Stored Procedure. What I did was I created a trigger with the following code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_ImportFile] 
ON  [dbo].[ReconMedicalAidFile] 
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    DECLARE @params VARCHAR(MAX),
            @ssisStr VARCHAR(MAX),
            @packageName VARCHAR(MAX),
            @serverName VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @serverName = 'ServerName'
    SET @packageName = 'MyIntegration'

    SET @ssisStr = 'dtexec /sq ' + @packageName + ' /ser ' + @serverName

    DECLARE @returnCode int
    EXEC @returnCode = xp_cmdshell @ssisStr

END
```

I get the following error *Procedure expects parameter 'command_string' of type 'varchar'.*

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went a different route. Still have the trigger but it will execute a SQL Job which contains the SSIS package.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'JobName' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it works when you replace **VARCHAR(MAX)** with **VARCHAR(8000)** data types